# Best way to extract array of values from json response

Tags: python, json

Consider the following json example:

```
{
   "results": [
      {
         "el": 42.96548843383789,
         "res": 19.08790397644043
      },
      {
         "el": 43.10981750488281,
         "res": 19.08790397644043
      }
      }
   ],
   "total": 2
}
```

I want to find out the easiest (without looping) way to get an array of all `el` values.  Is there a more condensed way to perform this than my code below?  Something like a 'jsonpath' expression or something, where I could just get all the values in one line.

```py
gresponse = json.loads(json_contents)
els = []
for result in (gresponse['results']):
    els.append(p['el'])
```

Comment: `els = [result['el'] for result in gresponse['results']]`?

Comment: nice, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
els = [result["el"] for result in gresponse["results"]]
```

Output:

```
[42.96548843383789, 43.10981750488281]
```